# POSTGRES union on timestamp with time zone

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to do a union where one of the columns is a timestamp with timezone.

```
 UNION(SELECT au.accountId AS accountid, 
                                u.id AS userId,
                                CAST (NULL AS INTEGER) AS searchprofileid,
                                u.name, 
                                u.email AS email, 
                                3 as searchitemtype,                                  
                                ac.name AS accountname,
                                null AS searchprofiletype,
                                false AS isdeleted,
                                false AS hashostednewsroom,
                                u.lockoutenabled AS lockoutenabled,
                                u.lockoutend AS lockoutend
                            FROM users u                              
                            LEFT JOIN accountusers au
                            ON u.id = au.userid
                            LEFT JOIN accounts ac
                            ON au.accountid = ac.id
                            WHERE u.name ILIKE '%%'
                            OR u.email ILIKE '%%'
                            LIMIT 5)ORDER BY
```

this is part of a larger union but i get this error:

UNION types text and timestamp with time zone cannot be matched

So i cast it to text like this u.lockoutend::text AS lockoutend
and that did work but then my backend (C#) failed when it tried to parse a string to a DateTimeOffset? . Why does it want lockoutend to be a text? And how can i do this?

EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
  accessfailedcount integer NOT NULL,
  concurrencystamp character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  email character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  emailconfirmed boolean NOT NULL,
  lockoutenabled boolean NOT NULL,
  lockoutend timestamp with time zone,
  name character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  normalizedemail character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  normalizedusername character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  passwordhash character varying(512) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  phonenumber character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  phonenumberconfirmed boolean NOT NULL,
  securitystamp character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  twofactorenabled boolean NOT NULL,
  username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  locale integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
```

C#

```
   using (var dbConnection = _dapperConnection.Open())
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Executing AdminSearchRepository.AdminSearch {sql}", sql);
            return await dbConnection.QueryAsync<DapperAdminSearchDto>(sql);
        }
```

Part of DapperAdminSearchDto:

```
   public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can we see your `c#` code, and maybe the db schema you're using? Maybe even the results of running `select u.lockoutend::text as lockoutend from users u`?

Comment: I think you're going to have to go the other way: whatever text column and date column you're trying to union together, you're going to have to explicitly convert the text column to a date. This will also solve the problem of C# being unable to treat it as a date. Don't ever try to convert everything to text and just hope that the code will magically un-screw everything and make it work - the first time your app gets installed in a different timezone all your text dates change meaning; 9/11 - is that 9th of Nov or 11th of Sept?

Comment: @CaiusJard but why does it want text? Why can't i use postgres timestamp with timezone (as the table columns uses) and parse that into DateTimeOffset?

Comment: I thought you said you had a text column (that I assumed contained dates, like `'2007-11-09 12:34:56 UTC+7'`) and a timestamp column that you were trying to union together (`SELECT mytextcolumnthathasadate FROM x UNION ALL SELECT mydatecolumn FROM y`) and you'd tried turning the date column into text, and were then finding an issue in c# not being able to interpret the string as a date.. My bad if this was not the case

Comment: We would have to see what is in the first statement, including structure of table providing this text representation of timestamp. Right now all we can do is guess but if in first statement you have text, then UNIONS need to be text as well: `SELECT now()::text UNION SELECT now() + interval '1 day'`